# How do we logically divide a Chatbot app meant to support both Slack & Microsoft Teams

Tags: design, architecture

We are building bot application that suppose to support both Slack & Teams. Both Slack & Team has a single Web hook endpoint which makes the app code tightly coupled with them and hard to make the core business logic verify-able.

Hence, we thought to divide our single monolith into two sub apps. Core & Slack Adapter. Core app is meant to perform slack-independent business logic and Slack Integration is meant to do Slack-specific operations (Events, Actions, Modals, etc) and also communicate with Core App to complete non-Slack works.

I'm not sure whether this problem would come under Backend-For-Frontend/API Proxy pattern or some other architecture/design.

We also need to leverage BoltJS for Slack interactions. Should we add BoltJS in both of our Apps or just the Slack Adapter App?

Microsoft Bot framework also attempts to solve similar problem but they their own architecture & design. Should we inspire on Bot framework and build adapter for Messenger platforms? Or, customize/build on top of Bot framework itself?

Edit: Adding use case to give some context.

Let's say that we want to build Slack & Teams integration for a Trello-like app. Which means, the user should be able to create an issue from Slack/Teams. Both Slack and Teams provide modal dialog where we inject our business logic to build custom dialog and data capturing.

Let's say, we require title, priority & assignee. Our app has to build this modal dialog as json and submit to to Slack for the dialog to appear. Our app has to handle both the Slack integration knowledge (web hooks, events, Slack validations, etc) and it needs to have domain knowledge -- what fields we should get from user if they can create an issue from Slack/Teams.

We thought to divide this knowledge into two -- the core/domain knowledge should be wrapped up in core and Slack/Teams specific stuff should go into their own app/service.

That way, when testing, we should be able to test whether the core behaves correctly by testing the endpoint directly by posting the payloads to core app.

Now, our app is monolith where we have everything to solve the domain problem as well as Slack/Teams integration logic that makes our current system hard to maintain, debug and add features. Hence, looking to divide the system to make it maintainable.

[image: Chatbot supports Slack & Teams]

Comment: Is there a specific part of integrating with both vendors that you have a question about? As this question is written, it is to broad to answer.

Comment: Can provide more information about the bot you are building? What does it do? Why does it need to communicate with Slack and Teams?

Comment: Why do you want to split the app into two apps? Things like interfaces for abstraction within a single app have existed for decades.

Comment: Added use case to give a context of why I'm keen on diving the app.